# Next-auth Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation" on signin with google oauth

Tags: next.js, prisma, next.js13, next-auth

I am trying to implement google oauth using NextAuth and Prisma. But I get following errors :-

My code looks like this -

1. connect.js :-

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
    let prisma;
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      prisma = new PrismaClient();
    } else {
      if (!global.prisma) {
        global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
      }
      prisma = global.prisma;
    }

    export default prisma;
```

2. auth.js :-

```
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
    import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
    import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
    import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
    import prisma from "./connect";

    export const authOptions = {
      adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
      providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
          clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
        }),
        GithubProvider({
          clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
        }),
      ],
    };

    export const getAuthSession = () => getServerSession(authOptions);
```

3. schema.prisma :-

```
generator client {
      provider = "prisma-client-js"
    }

    datasource db {
      provider = "mongodb"
      url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
    }

    model Account {
      id                String  @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
      userId            String
      type              String
      provider          String
      providerAccountId String
      refresh_token     String?
      access_token      String?
      expires_at        Int?
      token_type        String?
      scope             String?
      id_token          String?
      session_state     String?

      user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

      @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
    }

    model Session {
      id           String   @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
      sessionToken String   @unique
      userId       String
      expires      DateTime
      user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    }

    model User {
      id            String    @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
      name          String?
      email         String    @unique
      emailVerified DateTime?
      image         String?
      accounts      Account[]
      sessions      Session[]
      Post          Post[]
      Comment       Comment[]
    }

    model VerificationToken {
      identifier String   @id @map("_id")
      token      String   @unique
      expires    DateTime

      @@unique([identifier, token])
    }

    model Category {
      id    String  @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
      slug  String  @unique
      title String
      img   String?
      Posts Post[]
    }

    model Post {
      id        String    @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
      createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
      slug      String    @unique
      title     String
      desc      String
      img       String?
      views     Int       @default(0)
      catSlug   String
      cat       Category  @relation(fields: [catSlug], references: [slug])
      userEmail String
      user      User      @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email])
      comments  Comment[]
    }

    model Comment {
      id        String   @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
      createdAt DateTime @default(now())
      desc      String
      userEmail String
      user      User     @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email])
      postSlug  String
      post      Post     @relation(fields: [postSlug], references: [slug])
    }
```

[The error in the terminal shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwWxw.png)
[The error in the terminal shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQTnv.png)

[On trying to sign in with google, I get redirected to this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N69vF.png)

I tried a lot but am still getting this error.
I want to successfully login using google.
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Something seems wrong with DATABASE_URL. the error says db name is invalid. Make sure your DB_URL is correctly formatted

Comment: @CharmingRobot I checked the DATABASE_URL and I guess its correct. I have it in my .env file enclosed in double quotes.